# To determine the most likely dimensions of four subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

If the entries of a $3$ by $3$ matrix are chosen randomly between $0$ and $1$,what are the most likely dimensions of the four subspaces(column space,row space,null space and left nullspace)?

So in this case,can we conclude that most of the matrices will be singular?

Comment: There is no “most of the matrices.” There’s only one matrix

Comment: @StellaBidermanHow?What about the identity matrix?

Comment: @StellaBiderman Well, the question describes an algorithm for producing various $(2^9)$ matrices so..

Comment: @MathematicianByMistakeI didn't understand